# Why aren't more wifi points compromised?

Tags: defense, threat-mitigation, crime

Especially in light of the recent KRACK problem. Wifi has been compromised before; and undoubtedly it will again. So I have to wonder, why don't criminal organizations travel around major cities, planting devices near by important wifi networks locations ready to start cracking as soon as the next exploit is discovered?

It seems like it wouldn't be hard to develop a cheap battery powered device you could drop in a nearby alley, so when something like KRACK comes out, I would expect to hear of a wave of credit card frauds, as the criminals drive through the city, planting their devices, and getting access to all the data before it can be secured. Yet this doesn't seem to happen. There must be a reason for that. So, I wonder:

What are the security methods in place, that prevent this kind of thing from occuring? How are criminals stopped from from doing massive, wide-scale attacks after each vulnerability is discovered?

Comment: you assume that it is a technical or security constraint

Comment: see the other side of crime: theft. If you place some kind of devices somewhere, why shouldn't it be stolen? But beside that, I think this question is much to broad.

Comment: @Serverfrog They are stolen. Theft is a thing that happens. To extend the analogy: My question is like, if all the police took a weeks holiday at the same time, and the number of thefts did not increase.

Comment: "access to all the data" - in your scenario, that would be a massive amount of data to sort through - why go through all that effort when credit cards, bank accounts, and other personal data is up for sale in marketplaces where the chances of getting caught are nil? AND you can get exactly what you want instead of gigabytes of garbage to sift thru?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is always the same: money. It would cost a lot to deploy such an infrastructure (both in expenses and time), while there are  easier and less expensive ways to get credit cards number, be it by exploiting a vulnerability on a website to scoop up many numbers at once, or sending cheap phishing emails by million.

Furthermore, with the advent of TLS, a vulnerability on Wi-Fi network is not necessarily enough to get access to these information anyway.